# Removing line from header with createStackNavigator in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to remove the thin line that shows up at the top of createStackNavigator in react native.

I tried the below code but it didn't work

```
        loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
        UserLoginSelection: {
            screen: UserLoginSelection,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: '',
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                },
            },
        },
    },
  }
```

Can anyone please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `borderBottomWidth` to `0`:

```
// ...
headerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
}
// ...
```